# Changing the colour of actionbar hides the settings button

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-support-library, android-appcompat

I tried to change the colour of actionbar by making few changes in default theme.

[image]

But the problem is when the colour changes, it hides the settings button.please suggest me the changes.

Heres the xml file for styles.xml:

```
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">

       <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorWhite</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
    </style>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add the `android:textColorSecondary` attribute to your theme.

```
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">

    .....

    <!-- color of the menu overflow icon -->
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/my_color</item>

 </style>
```

Otherwise, since you are using a white `Toolbar`, you can use override the theme with:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
  app:theme="@style/ThemeToolbar" />
```

with:

```
<style name="ThemeToolbar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">

   <!-- navigation icon color -->
   <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/my_color</item>

    <!-- color of the menu overflow icon -->
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/my_color</item>
</style>
```

Comment: nothing just happened. I think its not the colour, something else is causing a problem. Because the settings button was there prior to any changes and now it is not showing for any  colour assigned to the action bar. If i click at the place where the setting button was prior to the changes, nothing happens. so i guess its the button which got lost somewhere while changing the action bar attribute. and i dont know how and what should be the problem.